# Como recuperar dados do localstore?

Tags: javascript

Como recupero itens que estão desta forma no `localStore`

```
lista-pessoas[{"name":"Hamburguer","adicao":"+carne","data":"2"}]
```

Comment: Acrescente mais detalhes a sua pergunta para que possa ser respondida. Em caso de dúvida sobre como fazer uma pergunta leia o Guia de Sobrevivência do StackOverflow https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas?cb=1

Comment: Eu gostaria de listar eles por exemplo:

Comment: Item: nome, nome , nome

Comment: Listar em uma div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resgatar o item do [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage) utilize o método [getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) e como foi salvo um texto e isso representa um objeto como demonstrado na sua pergunta precisa novamente ser convertido para um objeto com [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), um exemplo completo segue abaixo com gravação, recuperação e visualização da informação em uma lista:

```
//dados.
const data = [
    {"name":"Hamburguer 1","adicao":"+carne","data":"2"},
    {"name":"Hamburguer 2","adicao":"+carne","data":"2"},
    {"name":"Hamburguer 3","adicao":"+carne","data":"2"}
];

//gravando o dado no localStorage.
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));

//recuperando o dado do localStorage.
const textData = localStorage.getItem('data');
const newData = JSON.parse(textData);

//recuperando a tag da sua tela.
var ul = document.getElementById('tul');

//listando a informação.
newData.map(function(data, index) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(data.name)
    )   
    ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: ótimo e como exibo no html em uma div?

Comment: Consegui mano! Topppp

Comment: Só uma duvida como salvo os itens por exemplo um link que salva essas infirmações? por exemplo <a data-nome="BURGER1" data-valor="5.00">BURGER1</a>  <a data-nome="+CARNE" data-valor="1.00">+CARNE</a>  <a data-nome="+ALFACE" data-valor="1.00">+ALFACE</a>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o comando:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
```

fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem